# Find parent class from property

Tags: c#, regex, linq

Good afternoon,

I'm not really sure how to phrase my question, so please excuse anything that isn't relevant, and if I've left out anything important, please let me know! I'm also inexperienced with lambdas, regex, and linq, so do point anything out that I'm doing poorly/could be doing better.

My question is: can I get a reference to a class, from which I only know a property? Specifically, in the following code snippet, I'd like to change the index of 0, in `propertyValues[0]` to a variable stored on the same class. Is there something like, `this`, which accesses the parent?

For more context, I've pasted the relevant trimmed code bellow.

```
return Regex.Replace ( originalString, "{(.*?)}", match =>
    User.user.properties.First( property =>
        property.id == match.ToString ().Substring ( 1, match.ToString ().Length - 2 ))
            .propertyValues[0].adjectives[0]);



public class Property
{

    public string id;
    public List<Value> propertyValues = new List<Value> ();
    public sbyte propertyIndex;

}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

## EDIT

Thanks for the feedback, Philip Stuyck I'll try to do a better job of explaining.

I'm looking for, either, a way to get a reference to a property's parent class, or a way to create a local variable in a lambda expression. To illustrate, I have the following class, and return method.

Property class,

```
public class Property
{

    public string id;
    public List<Value> propertyValues = new List<Value> ();
    public sbyte propertyIndex;

}
```

User class,

```
public class User
{

    public static User user = new User ();

    internal List<Property> properties = new List<Property> ();
}
```

GetVariable method,

```
public static class GetVariable
{

    public static string FromUser ( string originalString )
    {

        return Regex.Replace ( originalString, "{(.*?)}", match => User.user.properties.First ( property => property.id == match.ToString ().Substring ( 1, match.ToString ().Length - 2 )).propertyValues[0].adjectives[0]);
    }
}
```

The `GetVariable.FromUser` method should return a new string, which has replaced every instance of a substring encased in brackets with a string from `User.user.properties`. So, it could be passed "This is a {Example}.", and return "This is a Demo" (if the User class had a property with the id Example, and a value of Demo).

My question is relating the GetVariable method, and more specifically, the last part: `propertyValues[0]`. I would like the index (currently 0), to be the variable on the Property class, which the `User.user.properties.First` delegate is finding.

So, ideally, it would be as simple as `User.user.properties.First ( property => property.id == match.ToString ()).propertyValues[property.propertyIndex]`, but I can't access property outside of the parentheses.

I hope this helped explain it, although I feel like it's still too complicated. If I can think of a better way to phrase my question, I'll do so. Also, I'll be happy to clarify anything via a comment.

Comment: Totally don't understand what you mean. Please rephrase completely.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Thanks for the comment! I've tried to rephrase my question, I hope it's more clear now. I'm not very good at explaining these kinds of questions, so please forgive my poor job earlier. If it's still too vague, please ask in the comments, so I can try to make it a little more clear. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. If you have a reference to a an object, you can get a potentially unknown property from it using Reflection, but you cannot find an arbitrary object when you have a property. This makes sense because if you have some property called `Id`, that could be a property on any object, so how would C# even attempt to start resolving that back to a Type - let alone a specific instance of that Type.

If you know what instance you have, you can can use reflection like so:

```
var myProperty = myInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
myProperty.SetMethod.Invoke(myInstance, new object[] {42});
//this will set the given property on the given 
//instance with the given value (42 in this example)
//GetMethod is also there 
//depending on what you need to do with it
```

However I should clarify that the above reflection only works with *Properties*, and in your example you have fields, so you would need to get FieldInfo which works a bit different than properties.

But in the example above it seems unclear, it looks like you have both an instance and know the type, so why can't you just use:

```
Regex.Replace ( 
   originalString, 
   "{(.*?)}", 
    match =>
        User.user.properties.First( property =>
        property.id == match.ToString().Substring( 1, 
                              match.ToString().Length - 2))
                .propertyValues[(int)property.propertyIndex]
                .adjectives[0]);
```

Unless I'm I'm not clear on what you are asking it looks like that would work?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I'm still taking a stab at it as your end goal isn't super clear, but it looks like what you are wanting is to wrap your match context in a method body so you can access the property that the match found multiple times before you lose scope to it.

Something like this I think it what you are looking for:

```
return Regex.Replace ( 
   originalString, 
   "{(.*?)}", 
    match => 
    {
        var matchStr = match.ToString()
        var formattedMatch = matchStr.Substring(1, matchStr.Length - 2);
        var prop = User.user.properties.First(
                 property => property.id == formattedMatch);
        return prop.propertyValues[(int)prop.propertyIndex].adjectives[0];
    }
```

**TL;DR**

I should probably mention as you said you were new to Linq and lambdas, essentially an `Expression<T>` or `LambdaExpression` is a `Func<TArgs..>` that is compiled at execution time rather than at compile time, so what you are doing when you write `c => c.Id == 42` is creating a method that looks like this:

```
internal static int _closureVariable = 42;
public static bool checkName(Property prop)
{
     return prop.Id == _closureVariable;
}
```

There is a little more involved with how it is treated and generated, but the end result is similar.

So in my example with a method body, I'm just creating a more complicated method that has a signature like this:

```
public static string matchRegex(Match match);
```

and then all the work is happening inside that method signature. It's important to remember that when there is no method body declared on an expression, the return keyword is implicit (i.e. `c => c.Name == "some name"` implicitly returns `true`) so if you have a method body(`c => { ... }`) you need to declare the return explicitly, or it will return void. (i.e. `c => { return c.Name == "some name"}`).

Comment: Tophallen, thank you for the response. I would like to do something similar to your latter example, but the `property` reference does not exist outside of the properties.First delegate. I was hoping to avoid reflection, also, but that may be what I have to do. Is there any way to assign a reference in a lambda expression?

Comment: I had no idea it was possible to create a method out of a delegate, thanks very much!

Comment: I included some explanation on how and why this works if you care, and perhaps it will clarify some things about Linq syntax and Expressions for you :)

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks for taking the time to outline how they work for me.